# "Would prefer to do something " vs. "would prefer doing something"

Tags: grammar

I've heard that it is grammatically incorrect to use a gerund after *would prefer*, for example, you say "I'*d prefer* to walk" not "I'*d prefer* walking".
But I'm almost sure that I have heard a sentence like "I'*d prefer* walking to driving".
I was wondering if it is because in the former there is only one option, whereas in the latter there are two options and you are comparing two things.
I know we can use a gerund after ***prefer***, as in "I prefer driving." Is it also possible to use it after ***would prefer***, and say "I'd prefer driving"?

Comment: It's not clear to me what the question is.

Comment: "it is grammatically incorrect" -- source?

Comment: "I would prefer to" requires a verb, not a noun. A gerund like "walking" here would be a noun, not a verb: "I'd prefer walking to driving" -- *walking* and *driving* are nouns here.

Comment: @Kris Source: English Grammar in Use

Comment: @Kris, I would prefer strawberry to chocolate. That sounds grammatical to me.

Comment: @dangph There's no ***to*** in your hungry statement :)

Comment: @Kris, yes there is: I'd prefer strawberry **to** chocolate. It's the same shape as Cheiloproclitic's sentence: I'd prefer walking to driving.

Comment: @dangph That *to* has nothing to do with the question. That *to* = *over* not "intention."

Comment: But what does English Grammar in Use say about this? I think you are correct that either phrasing works, so I wonder whether you might have misinterpreted what the book said. I don't have a copy of it, so please cite the relevant text from book.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock This is what the book reads:  "We say 'would prefer **to do** something' (_not_ doing): 'I'd prefer to drive.' (not I'd prefer driving)

Comment: The book also reads: "We use **would prefer** to say what someone wants in a specific situation (not in general).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use gerunds if you're using *would* in a conditional statement, e.g.

> I would prefer walking over driving if my legs were in better shape.

But if you're just making a general statement about your preferences, *would prefer* is normally followed by a verb.